# Wget fetches typo3temp instead of the page tree

Tags: wget, typo3-9.x

I try to use wget to fetch the all the sites of my typo3 project. The target is to make a cronjob with this command to build the cache and the search index. While testing the command wget shows a weird behaviour.

The OS is Opensuse Tumbleweed running Apache and MySQL.

Typo3 9.5.9 was installed via composer. The composer.json is in /srv/www/typo3install, Documentroot ist /srv/www/htdocs.
The environment module of typo3 says all my permissions are ok (htaccess difference for static file cache).
This is my site configuration (config.yaml):

```
rootPageId: 1
base: /
baseVariants: {  }
languages:
  -
    title: Deutsch
    enabled: true
    languageId: '0'
    base: /
    typo3Language: de
    locale: de_DE.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: de
    navigationTitle: Deutsch
    hreflang: de
    direction: ''
    flag: de
  -
    title: English
    enabled: true
    languageId: '1'
    base: /en/
    typo3Language: default
    locale: en_UK.UTF-8
    iso-639-1: en
    navigationTitle: English
    hreflang: en
    direction: ''
    fallbackType: fallback
    fallbacks: '0'
    flag: gb
errorHandling: {  }
routeEnhancers:
  PageTypeSuffix:
    type: PageType
    map:
      sitemap.xml: 1533906435
routes:
  -
    route: robots.txt
    type: staticText
    content: "User-agent: *\r\n\r\n# Only allow URLs generated with RealURL\r\nDisallow: /*?id=*\r\nDisallow: /*&id=*\r\n\r\n# L=0 is the default language\r\nDisallow: /*?L=0*\r\nDisallow: /*&L=0*\r\n\r\n# typeNum = 98 is usually the print version.\r\nDisallow: /*?type=98*\r\nDisallow: /*&type=98*\r\n\r\n# Should always be protected (.htaccess)\r\nDisallow: /*/Private/*\r\nDisallow: /fileadmin/templates/html/*\r\nDisallow: /*/Configuration/*\r\n\r\nDisallow: /typo3temp/*\r\nAllow: /typo3temp/*.css\r\nAllow: /typo3temp/*.css.*.gzip\r\nAllow: /typo3temp/*.js\r\nAllow: /typo3temp/*.js.*.gzip\r\nAllow: /typo3temp/*.jpg\r\nAllow: /typo3temp/*.gif\r\nAllow: /typo3temp/*.png\r\n\r\nDisallow: *.sql\r\nDisallow: *.sql.gz\r\n\r\nDisallow: /typo3/\r\nDisallow: /typo3_src/\r\nDisallow: /template/\r\nAllow: /typo3/sysext/frontend/Resources/Public/*\r\nAllow: /template/Resources/Public/*\r\nSitemap: localhost/sitemap.xml\r\nSitemap: localhost/sitemap.xml"
disableStaticFileCache: false
```

The httpd.conf for the documentroot:

```
<Directory "/srv/www/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
</Directory>
```

The command:

```
wget -v -r http://localhost -P /srv/www/htdocs/typo3temp/tmpbuild
```

This fetches only the content of /srv/www/htdocs/typo3temp. But if I start with a subpage of the page tree the whole site gets fetched:

```
wget -v -r http://localhost/products/ -P /srv/www/htdocs/typo3temp/tmpbuild
```

I think this is not the behaviour as it should be: starting with the base URL should fetch the whole tree.
I can´t figure out if i have missed an option of wget or if there is something wrong with my configuration.

Thanks in advance,
Starger.

P.S.: Creating a hidden subpage and use this as a starting point works. But this is just a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do some changes (switch to HTTP2 and SSL) on the server and the problem seems to be not present anymore.